# HTML/CSS/JS - Adaptable grid layout?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some (unknown height) elements that adjust themselves horizontally with `float: left;`, but if one of those elements is taller, there is a space over the one in the next row. I'd like to move that element to the empty space over it. Here's a picture of the problem: [image: Empty space over element, must move it there]
Is it possible to do this without JavaScript? Either way, how can I do this?

Comment: If you use jQuery you could use isotope: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: Try to add for each box `clear: left;` or right maybe it will be enough for now.

Comment: @Gustonez Do you know how floats and clear work or are you guessing from trial and errors?

Comment: Of course I know, but I was on mobile I couldn't give him an example. here's a quick example of course it could be better if we use columns http://jsfiddle.net/tkrRv/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use javascript! jquery masonry was made for this!

http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Perfect! Using the vanilla verison.

Answer (score 1):

In CSS without JS:

- you could have "Fotos" vertically aligned relative to "Contato" with `display: inline-block` (whitespace is a bit annoying and there's an equivalent for IE6/7 if needed)
- you could have blocks of equal heights on each "line" either with *faux-columns* or CSS table layout (unrelated to unsemantic HTML table layout with `table`, `tr` and `td` elements. Here it's *layout* with the elements of your choice)
- if you want to stack as much blocks as possible, then you'll have to create 2 columns, float them and stuff them with your blocks. This would change their order in your HTML code as they'd be written from top to bottom and then left to right ("Fotos" would come right after "Home" in the HTML code)